# In Mysql query DATE_SUB not returning expected result

Tags: mysql, database, date, select

Here is my Mysql query

```
SELECT COUNT(*) CallCnt,ANBCnt, t2.Duration,(ANB) Number,
  ((DATE_SUB('2012-12-10 05:22:30',
              INTERVAL (SELECT CONCAT(''',t2.Duration:0,''')) MINUTE_SECOND))) Mintime,
  ('2012-12-10 05:22:30') Maxtime,
  (1) TYPE,
  (t1.CallTypeId) 
FROM cdr_temp1_check t1
  INNER JOIN cdr_temp1_check_details t2 
  ON t1.CallTypeId=t2.CallTypeId
WHERE TimeStamp1 >= DATE_SUB('2012-12-10 05:22:30',
                              INTERVAL (SELECT CONCAT(''',t2.Duration:0,''')) MINUTE_SECOND) 
  AND TimeStamp1<='2012-12-10 05:22:30'
GROUP BY ANB 
  HAVING COUNT(*) > ANBCnt
```

Result returned is

```
    CallCnt  ANBCnt  Duration      Number  Mintime              Maxtime                TYPE  CallTypeId
-------  ------  --------  ----------  -------------------  -------------------  ------  ----------
    267      40        25      2042011234  2012-12-10 05:20:30  2012-12-10 05:22:30       1           5
    134      20        15      9895697970  2012-12-10 05:20:30  2012-12-10 05:22:30       1           3
```

Expected Result

```
    CallCnt  ANBCnt  Duration      Number  Mintime              Maxtime                TYPE  CallTypeId
-------  ------  --------  ----------  -------------------  -------------------  ------  ----------
    267      40        25      2042011234  2012-12-10 04:57:30  2012-12-10 05:22:30       1           5
    134      20        15      9895697970  2012-12-10 04:57:30  2012-12-10 05:22:30       1           3
```

Column showing issue is the Mintime which should be `Maxtime minus Duration`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to try a different approach.

Given that maxtime is just a string that you are entering into the query. You could use DATE_SUB to substract the desired interval directly

```
((DATE_SUB('2012-12-10 05:22:30',
INTERVAL t2.Duration MINUTE))) Mintime
```

so your entire query would be:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) CallCnt,ANBCnt,
t2.Duration,(ANB) Number,
((DATE_SUB('2012-12-10 05:22:30',
INTERVAL t2.Duration MINUTE))) Mintime,
('2012-12-10 05:22:30') Maxtime,(1) TYPE,
(t1.CallTypeId) FROM cdr_temp1_check t1
INNER JOIN cdr_temp1_check_details t2 ON t1.CallTypeId=t2.CallTypeId
WHERE TimeStamp1>=DATE_SUB('2012-12-10 05:22:30',
INTERVAL t2.Duration MINUTE) 
AND TimeStamp1<='2012-12-10 05:22:30'
GROUP BY ANB HAVING COUNT(*)>ANBCnt
```